# How to use a "-" in Access DLookup Function Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having trouble using a "-" (dash) in an Access DLookup function criteria.

I have two unbound textboxes called `txt_PN` and `txt_PO_Number`. When a user clicks a button, I want to search the db for records where both the part number (txt_PN) and PO number (txt_PO_number) exist in the same record.

The problem I'm having is that if a user enters a part number with a "-" the DLookup function doesn't find the record...even if one exists. DLookup works perfectly for part numbers without dashes.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
PartCheck = DLookup("Part_Number", "Tbl 01 RDM DB", "Part_Number = '" & Me.txt_PN & "'")

POCheck = DLookup("PO_Number", "Tbl 01 RDM DB", "Part_Number = '" & Me.txt_PN & "'")
```

If anyone can help me accomodate the use of dashes, it would be very much appreciated.

P.S. The "-" doesn't necessarily appear in the same place from one part number to the next.

Comment: You're saying that some part numbers have dashes and some do not? So that the dash actually is important?

Comment: Is `Part_Number` a lookup field?

Comment: Does your code throw an error, or is the problem just that the `DLookup` expressions always return Null when `Me.txt_PN` contains a dash?

Comment: That is correct: some part numbers contain dashes and others do not. And the numbers that do contain dashes, the location of the dash is not consistent.

Comment: And the code does not throw an error. The purpose of the search is so a user can request priority for parts that have yet to arrive. If they enter a part number and a PO number that are already in the db, they are notified that the record already exists. If the part and PO number doesn't exist, an email is sent to appropriate individuals, notifying them of the priority. As it's behaving now, when a user enters a part number with a dash, even if the part number exists in the database on the PO they're looking for, the db doesn't find the record and sends the email. No error is generated.

Comment: Part_Number is a column in the db backend table.

Comment: Is that a typo in your code, or are you actually looking for "Part_Number" in "Tbl 01 RDM DB" where "Part_Number = '" & Me.txt_PN & "'").  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't you also need to ensure that you are checking for the PO and PN at the same time.  I would imagine that there may be many POs for any PN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem...sort of. I'm not sure how the dash problem got resolved, but using the code:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("PO_Number", "Tbl 01 RDM DB", "PO_Number = '" & Me.txt_PO_Number & "' And Part_Number = '" & Me.txt_PN & "'")) Then 

[rest of code]

End If
```

all part numbers are recognized and the program works the way I would like. Thank you all for the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to perform a query and check if there are any records.

Modified from [this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?327269):

```
Dim rsPNCheck As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Tbl 01 RDM DB] WHERE Part_Number = '" & Me.txt_PN & "' AND PO_Number = '" & Me.txt_PO & "';"

Set rsPNCheck = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute(strSQL)
If Not rsPNCheck.EOF Then
    ' Notify user record exists
Else
    ' send email
End If
Set rsPNCheck = Nothing
```